# SQL get grouped field ordered by lastest modified row

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a table document (id, name, id_expedient, creation_date, modify_date). A expedient can have several documents.
I have a document id and I want to find an expedient whose last modified (or created) document is the one I have selected in Oracle SQL

For example

```
id  name            id_expedient    creation_date           modify_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   doc Monday      exp A           2/11/2015               
2   doc Tuesday     exp B           2/10/2015       
3   doc Friday      exp C           2/09/2015                       
4   doc Thursday    exp C           2/01/2015               2/08/2015
```

If I search document id:

```
1 the result must be Exp A

2 the result must be Exp B

3 the result must be Exp C

4 the result must be void, because doc Thursday is not the lastest modified document of Exp C (that would be doc 3)
```

I tried doing subqueries, but I couldn't obtain the lastest modified document of an expedient

```
SELECT id_exp
from TB_DOCUMENT doc1
where doc1.doc_id IN 
    (select TOP 1 DOC2.doc_id FROM
        (SELECT DOC2.doc_id, NVL(MODIFY_DATE,CREATION_DATE) AS DateC
        FROM TB_DOCUMENT DOC2
        WHERE DOC2.id_exp = doc1.id_exp)
    ORDER by DateC DESC)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Oracle, why do you have SQL Server syntax in your query?

Comment: It was just an example. Oracle is what I have to use to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you should also to clarify better what you expect. 4 returns nothing, because exp C has also a creation date more recent with ID 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
  from TB_DOCUMENT t
 where (id_expedient, 
        coalesce(modify_date, 
                 creation_date
                )
       ) in (select id_expedient, 
                    max(coalesce(modify_date, creation_date))
               from TB_DOCUMENT sub
              where t.id_expedient = sub.id_expedient
                    group by id_expedient)
   and t.id = YOUR_ID
```

The subquery in the where condition allows you to get only the rows with the max creation or modification date for each `id_expedient`.

I have created a demo in [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83e84/11).

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I needed. Thank you very much, you 've been so much considered creating the Fiddler demo :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to return a row for each expedient

```
SELECT id_expedient 
  FROM (SELECT id_expedient, max(NVL(modify_date, creation_date))
    FROM document
    GROUP BY id_expedient
        );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53997f/15

Comment: OK sorry, this was my fault, HAVING with agg on Oracle doesn't work, at least not like I did. 
SELECT id_expedient 
  FROM (SELECT id_expedient, max(NVL(modify_date, creation_date))
    FROM document
    GROUP BY id_expedient
        ); this should do